# Unable to removeLayers from Map

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, feature-layer

I was trying to create a FeatureLayer from the features returned from the [ViewShed GP](http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Elevation/ESRI_Elevation_World/GPServer/Viewshed) and I was successful at doing [it](http://msgist2011.grd.arizona.edu/project/gp_test.html). So when I click on the map, that featureSet is sent to the GP Tool and the return has all the features and I add it to the map as a FeatureLayer. Now I want to remove the layer when the user clicks again on the map, but strangely, the `map.layerIds` returns, `["layer0"]`, indicating only the basemap.

I am not sure how to remove the featureLayer? This is my code,

```
function init() {
    dojo.connect(map, "onClick", computeViewShed);
}

function computeViewShed(evt) {
    map.graphics.clear();
    map.removeLayer("finalLayer"); //finalLayer is the id that I assigned to the featureLayer that I am adding

    var pointSymbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol();
    pointSymbol.setSize(20);
    pointSymbol.setOutline(new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new dojo.Color([0, 0, 0]), 1));
    pointSymbol.setColor(new dojo.Color([0, 0, 255, 0.25]));

    var graphic = new esri.Graphic(evt.mapPoint, pointSymbol);
    map.graphics.add(graphic);

    var features = [];
    features.push(graphic);
    var featureSet = new esri.tasks.FeatureSet();
    featureSet.features = features;
    var vsDistance = new esri.tasks.LinearUnit();
    vsDistance.distance = 5;
    vsDistance.units = "esriMiles";
    var params = {
        "Input_Observation_Point": featureSet,
        "Viewshed_Distance": vsDistance
    };
    gp.execute(params, drawViewshed);
}

function drawViewshed(results, messages) {
    var polySymbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol();
    polySymbol.setOutline(new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new dojo.Color([0, 0, 0, 0.5]), 1));
    polySymbol.setColor(new dojo.Color([255, 127, 0, 0.7]));
    var features = results[0].value.features;
    var layerDefinition = {
        "geometryType": "esriGeometryPolygon",
        "fields": [{
            "name": "OBJECTID",
            "alias": "ID",
            "type": "esriFieldTypeOID"
        }, {
            "name": "grid_code",
            "alias": "Grid Number",
            "type": "esriFieldTypeString"
        }, {
            "name": "Shape_Area",
            "alias": "Area",
            "type": "esriFieldTypeNumber"
        }]

    }
    var featureCollection = {
        "layerDefinition": layerDefinition,
        "featureSet": {
            "features": features,
            "geometryType": "esriGeometryPolygon"
        }
    };
    //create a feature layer based on the feature collection
    featureLayer = new esri.layers.FeatureLayer(featureCollection, {
        id: 'finalLayer',
        mode: esri.layers.FeatureLayer.MODE_SNAPSHOT
    });
    map.addLayers([featureLayer]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was simple just needed to fetch the id of the grpahics layer and add it to getLayer.

`map.removeLayer(map.getLayer(map.graphicsLayerIds[0]));`